# How to dynamically add a button with an event listener to the DOM?

Tags: html, dom, button, dom-manipulation

I have added an element as follows:

```
var number = document.createElement( 'div' );
number.className = 'number';
number.innerHTML = '<div><button id="row">ROW</button></div>';
//number.textContent = (i/8) + 1;
element.appendChild (number);
```

I have a button event listener as follows:

```
var button = document.getElementById( 'row' );
button.addEventListener( 'click', function ( event ) {
    transform( targets.row, 1000 );
}, false );
```

Although the div tag shows up in the floating div tag, it does not respond to the transform function.
Can anyone assist me in finding out why it is not picking up the click?

The example can be found at http://www.kreativperspektiv.com/pb2

UPDATE:
Prior to reading the response below, I just added a click event handler to the code which seems to work.

```
var xcollapse = document.createElement( 'div' );
xcollapse.className = 'xcollapse'; xcollapse.innerHTML = '<button onclick="transform( targets.row, 1000 )">Expand</button><button onclick="transform( targets.table, 1000 )">Collapse</button>';
element.appendChild( xcollapse );
```

This seems to work but I'm sure there is a more elegant solution.  Such as it would be nice to click the object to expand and click it to contract without having specific buttons detailing those actions.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: http://jsbin.com/cedawu/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score -1):

It is not considered best practice to add your child elements to a parent element using innerHTML:

```
number.innerHTML = '<div><button id="row">ROW</button></div>';
```

If you want to dynamically add elements to the DOM you should do like this:

```
var numberDiv = document.createElement( 'div' );
numberDiv.className = 'number';

var buttonDiv = document.createElement( 'div' );
numberDiv.appendChild('buttonDiv');

var button = document.createElement( 'button' );
button.id = 'row';
buttonDiv.appendChild('button');

var buttonText = document.createTextNode("ROW") 
button.appendChild( buttonText );

element.appendChild (number);

button.addEventListener( 'click', function ( event ) {
    transform( targets.row, 1000 );
}, false );
```

Read more on DOM manipulation [here](http://callmenick.com/post/basics-javascript-dom-manipulation)

But according to @Quentin (see his comment) both should work so the problem in your code is probably somewhere else. Maybe you can add more details to the question.

Comment: "This is not the way to add your child elements to a parent element." — You could argue about best practises, but the code in the question works, so this shouldn't make any difference

Comment: @Quentin My bad. I assumed (I should have tested) this might be causing a faulty connection to the event listener. I updated the answer. I guess something relevant is missing in the question.

Comment: I really like your response.  I appreciate it greatly.  I'm still understanding the DOM manipulation and will read up on that.